# awk script doesn't working with gsub $10

Tags: linux, awk

I have a lot of form letter need generate.

```
    $>cat debug-form-letter
    The first field is $1, the second $2, the third $3,
    the 10th field is $10,but  the 10th correct value  is varA.



    $> cat debug-replace-value
    var1|var2|var3|var4|var5|var6|var7|var8|var9|varA|varB



    $> cat debug-replace-form-letter.awk
    BEGIN {FS = "|"
                       while (getline <"debug-form-letter")
                       line[++n] = $0
       }
    {for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {  
                       s = line[i]         
                       for (j = 1; j <= NF; j++)  
                                  gsub("\\$"j, $j, s)
                       print s
               }
       }
```

I called by this

```
    $> awk -f debug-replace-form-letter.awk debug-replace-value
```

--10 I want to get like this

```
    The first field is var1, the second var2, the third var3,

    the 10th field is varA,but  the 10th correct value  is varA.
```

--20 but I get this

```
    The first field is var1, the second var2, the third var3,

    the 10th field is var10,but  the 10th correct value  is varA.
```

the above $10 is not correct ,it is become $1 plus 0,I try to double quote and 
 single quote ,it's not working too.

AND $11 is become $1 plus 1.

my awk is 4.1.3 ,and I update to the latest version it's not working too.

```
    $> awk -V
    GNU Awk 4.1.3, API: 1.1
    Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2015 Free Software Foundation.
```

what's wrong with my script?how can I make it working?

Comment: solved,see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50322499/awk-script-doesnt-working-correctly-with-gsub-10

Comment: A comment is not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

When replacing `$1` you also replace the initial part of `$10` (and `$11`, and `$12` etc.).  `$1` is replaced by `var1` so `$10` is replaced by `var10` (`var1` and the left over `0` from `$10`).

You have to be more specific with your regular expression so that you only match the specific number that you are concerned with, and nothing more.

There are two ways of doing this correctly:

1. Modify the regular expression in the substitution so that it matches the correct thing (difficult).
2. Do the matching of the longest strings first, for example by substituting them in the order from `$10` to `$1` instead of from `$1` to `$10` (or however many variables you have).

Using the second option:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { split($0, vars, "|"); next }
     { for (i = length(vars); i >= 1; --i) gsub("\\$" i, vars[i]) } 1' debug-replace-value debug-form-letter
```

For the given texts, this generates

```
The first field is var1, the second var2, the third var3,
the 10th field is varA,but  the 10th correct value  is varA.
```